# Interpretation of a phrase

Tags: grammar, particle-と

> 侍は一旦護ると決めたものは死んでも護る

The Samurai even if he die, he protect what he decided to protect.

護ると決めたもの = Something that was decided to protect.

How do you guys understand this phrase ?

Comment: Can you explain what you don't understand?

Comment: I am not sure if the interpretation of this (護ると決めたもの   ), is right.

Comment: Your first interpretation (The Samurai even if he die, he protect what he decided to protect) looks fine. Your second (Something that was decided to protect) is a little dubious since the original sentence is not in the passive voice, but I think you already know this.

Comment: Oh, Thank you! Know I understand. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All actions in the sentence are done by the samurai. The following is unnaturally verbose and possibly not grammatical but if we try to imagine it like this:

侍は一旦(侍が)護ると(侍が)決めたものは(侍が)死んでも(侍が)護る

very literally:

Samurai, once {(samurai will protect...)<-[if samurai decided]} something, even if (samurai) dies, (samurai) will protect.

Or, more naturally:

> Once samurai decided to protect something, he'll protect it even if he dies.